# If $S$ is symmetric, then its image of linear operator $Λ(S)$ is symmetric.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces over the real numbers, and let $Λ : X → Y$ be a
bounded linear operator. Prove that If $S$ is symmetric, then its image $Λ(S)$ is symmetric.

My attempt:

I have some problem to know where we need the boundedness of the operator and completeness of the spaces is needed?. Or my solution has flaws?

Let $-a,a \in S$ then $\Lambda a ,\Lambda(-a) \in \Lambda (S)$. We can also write  $\Lambda (S) \ni  \Lambda(-a) = -\Lambda a$ so it is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires only the fact that $\Lambda$ is linear but the way you have written the proof is not correct. Pick any point $y$ in $\Lambda (S)$. Then $y=\Lambda (x)$ for  some $x \in S$. By hyptothesis  $-x \in S$ so $-y=-\Lambda (x)=\Lambda (-x) \in \Lambda (S)$.